# Ruby On Rails - empty object reference? (newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object-reference, isnullorempty

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, but has quite some experience in other OO programming.

Has got stuck though - it seems - when trying to create a simple blog application following this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

In point 5.7 (Showing Posts), the values from the form should be displayed on screen, but my display is just empty:

Title:

Text:

???

Would really appreciate any tips to where the error might be !

... don't know if the code below is sufficient to narrow it down, otherwise let me know of course.

Thank you very much for any help!

/Johan

---

My show.html.erb file is simply:

```
<p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Text:</strong>
    <%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

but seems that @post reference an empty object?

--

Here is my posts_controller.rb file:

class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params[:post])

    @post.save
    #render text: params[:post].inspect
    redirect_to @post   
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

end

(the render text: command displays the parameters correctly)

--

Comment: It might be a record is created with title and text equal to nil.

Answer (score 0):

In your create action you should have:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

instead of `@post = Post.new(post_params[:post])`